Is every automorphism of a cone diagonalisable?
Let $V$ be a real, finite-dimensional vector space, and let $C\subset V$ be a closed convex cone, with nonempty interior, and such that $C\cap (-C)=\{0\} $. Let $u\in\operatorname{GL}(V) $ such that $u(C)=C$. Is $u$ diagonalisable [edit: i.e., diagonalizable over $\mathbf{C}$]?
Note that there are a number of hypotheses under which this holds (see for instance this paper), but I don't know whether it holds in general.

One can take another point of view and wonder, given an invertible self-operator $T$, whether it preserves a cone (salient, nonempty interior). In dimension 2 it is easy to see which ones do (namely reflections and positive diagonalizable). In dimension 3, in view of the answer, the unipotent (identity + rank 2) one also does. In such an approach, one has to figure out what is the cone generated by one orbit $T^\mathbf{Z}v$, which does not sound completely obvious to me.

The question is settled in the negative but I just mention a maybe relevant source of counter-examples, namely the so-called parabolic automorphisms of algebraic surfaces. The following paper of J. Grivaux gives a useful exposition: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.1771

No, see Example 6.1 in Tam's and Schneider's paper On the Core of a Cone-Preserving Map. For completeness, I will write the counterexample here, but the details can be found in the paper.
Let $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and consider the cone $C = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 2xz - y^2 \geq 0 \text{ and } x \geq 0 \}$. Then for
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
we have $AC = C$, but $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. It is true, however, that any automorphism of a cone which has an eigenvector in the interior of the cone is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. In this case, the condition does not hold as the only eigenvector lies on the boundary.
References
Tam, Bit-Shun; Schneider, Hans, On the core of a cone-preserving map, Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 343, No. 2, 479-524 (1994). ZBL0826.15015.

Is there an example with a polyhedral cone?

@SamHopkins no, then it will be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. See Corollary 3.4 and Theorem 3.5 of the mentioned paper.

Every $u\in\mathrm{SO}(3)$ preserves a lot of such cones ($u$ fixes a nonzero vector $\xi$ and hence round cones around $\mathbf{R}_+\xi$) but, up to a few exceptions, $u$ is not diagonalizable.
If instead you were asking about being diagonalizable over $\mathbf{C}$, isometries cannot any longer provide a counterexample but the slightly more elaborate example in the previous answer applies anyway.

Thanks! I was indeed meaning diagonalizable over $\Bbb{C}$, I should have made it clear. Anyway, as you say the previous answer settles the question.
